# Number of possible palindrome anagrams for a given word

Tags: algorithm, math, combinatorics, palindrome, anagram

I have to find No. of  palindrome anagrams are possible for a given word.
Suppose the word is `aaabbbb`.My approach is

> 1. Prepare a hash map that contains no. of time each letter is appearing
>
>    For my example it will be
>
>    ```
>    a--->3
>    b--->4
>    ```
>
>    1. If length of string is even then no. of occurrence of each letter should be even to form palindrome     of given word else no of
>         palindrome anagrams is 0
>    2. If length of string is odd then at max one occurrence of letter can be odd and other should be even.

This two above steps was for finding that weather a given word can can form palindrome or not.

Now for finding no of palindrome anagrams, what approach should I follow?

Comment: Use combinatorics. How many ways are there to arrange half of the letters?

Comment: But what should I do for repeated letter

Comment: The number of ways that `n` a's and `m` b's can be ordered when all a's and b' are considered equivalent is `(a + b)! / (a! * b!)` That expands to more than two letters: `(sum(n_i))! / prod(n_i!)`. Take care not to overflow the factorials.

Comment: I agree with @MOehm: this is math, not an algorithm. Also, in (ii), you say "at max one ... can be odd". To be more precise, one and only one letter MUST have an odd number. It's not "max" because there must be exactly one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing to notice is that if the word is an odd length, then there must be exactly one character with an odd number of occurrences.  If the word is an even length, then there must be no characters with an odd number of occurrences.  In either case, you're looking for how many ways you can arrange the pairs of characters.  You're looking for the number of permutations since order matters:

n = number of character pairs (aaaabbb would have 3 pairs, aabbcccc would have 4 pairs)

(n)!/( number_of_a_pairs! * number_of_b_pairs! * etc..)

So in the aaaabbb case, you're finding the permutations of aab:

3!/2!1! = 3

baa = baabaab

aba = abababa

aab = aabbbaa

And in the aabbcccc case, you're finding the permutations of abcc:

4!/2! = 12:
abcc
acbc
accb
bacc
bcac
bcca
cabc
cacb
cbac
cbca
ccab
ccba

Comment: According to your algorithm the answer for "aaa" would be 3.But in actual it should be 1.Please clarify